# Get access to the clicked html element from the new page triggered by click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, html

I have the following html code in page_1:

```
<article>
    <div>
        <img src="img.png">
    </div>
        <div id="text_a"> first article was clicked</div>
        <a href="page_2" ></a>
</article>
   <article>
    <div>
        <img src="img_2.png">
    </div>
        <div id="text_b"> second article was clicked</div>
        <a href="page_2"></a>
</article>
```

I would like to get the text attached to the article element that was clicked (e.g. 'second article was clicked') after I clicked the href 
and print it in page_2.

Comment: Failry simple with [`jQuery  load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) assuming your pages are on same domain and you use it in page_2 to pull text from page_1

Comment: charlietfi can you share an example .

Comment: There are examples in the docs in link I provided...as well as all over the web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`load`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) method:

On `page_2`:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$("#result").load("page_1.html #abc, .cde");
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I access the text when I don't know which element was clicked?  There are many of these article elements with different text in each.

Comment: You can just get the whole page's text, then filter that string.

Comment: @moreo one suggestion is pass a query param in url based on which one is clicked and parse the page_2 url to get which item to filter out

Comment: But how would I know if it was clicked ? - I have edited the question above to make the problem clearer.

Comment: @moreo change the `href` like `href="page_2?article=text_b"`. Easy to research how to parse the query string in url and pass that value to `load()` url

Comment: You'd use a URL parameter for that.